# Include apk signature within the java code to validate it at runtime

Tags: java, android

I've been doing some reverse engineering on an APK and I found that these guys kept the signature in base64 stored as a static attribute of a class so that they can validate whether or not the current signature of the APK is valid by comparing them.

My questions, after a lot of research, would be:

1) How can they calculate the signature and then hardcode it in the code? Wouldn't that change the signature after they modify the java code to include it?

2) Which pieces of the APK are used to calculate the signature?

Well, I hope this is clear enough and if you have any doubt please let me know and I'll edit.

Thanks!!

Comment: If you are seeing them refer to the `android.content.pm.Signature` class, that's really the X.509 certificate of the public key of the keypair used to sign the app, not the app's actual digital signature.

Comment: From the documentation:

Opaque, immutable representation of a signing certificate associated with an application package.

This class name is slightly misleading, since it's not actually a signature.

Thanks a lot dude!
I had tried everything but get suspicious of the name of the class.

Answer (score 0):

`android.content.pm.Signature` is a poorly-named class. It really is an encoded edition of the X.509 certificate of the public portion of the signing key.

Note that their defense is largely pointless. Perhaps it will catch some inexperienced or stupid attackers, but everyone else will just change the comparison value as part of whatever modifications that they are making to the app.

Where "signature" checking *can* be useful is in validating the signing key of other apps, under the premise that you might be untouched but they might be repackaged apps.

Comment: Exactly. That's what I did as soon as I saw this validation. The problem was I got confused about how they did it after I changed the comparison, since I thought that Signature was in fact a signature.

Agreed with that scenario where validating signing keys could be useful, but as we said before, it only takes to modify the validation in every app involved and that does the trick.